# Clipping a 3D plot with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

How can I clip the paths of a 3D plot to the 3D axis bounding box? I am not talking about clipping the path to the *projection* of the bounding box (which pgfplots does by default), I want to remove points that lie outside the box in 3D.

Consider the following plot:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin = -1.1, xmax = 1.1,
             ymin = -1.1, ymax = 1.1,
             zmin = -1.1, zmax = 1.1]
\addplot3[domain = -1:1,samples = 20,
          samples y = 0, very thick] (0, 0, {2 * x});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Not clipped]

What I want (without changing the plot formula), is this:

[image: Correctly clipped]

Note that markers *are* clipped to the box: change `\addplot3` to `\addplot3+`, and markers will appear on the part inside the box, but not on the part outside.

[image: Markers are clipped]

I tried various `clip` options from the manual, but so far nothing I tried was successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `restrict z to domain` key. It can be applied for the entire axis or per-plot, whichever you require.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin = -1.1, xmax = 1.1,
             ymin = -1.1, ymax = 1.1,
             zmin = -1.1, zmax = 1.1]
\addplot3[domain = -1:1,samples = 20,
          samples y = 0, very thick,
          restrict z to domain={-1.1:1.1}] (0, 0, {2 * x});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Now that I know what it is called, a note to future readers: `restrict x to domain` and `restrict y to domain` also exist.